# Calling .net dll function from actionscript

Tags: .net, actionscript-3

I have an adobe air application running on windows.

I would like to call functions in third party dlls from actionscript.

Is this possible?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you would need to extend AIR using Native Extensions

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html