# Convert .Net DLL to Flash Library?

Tags: c#, silverlight, dll, actionscript, equivalent

I've made an .Net Dynamic Link Library, written in c#, to be used in Silverlight applications.

Now, I want to have the same kind of functionallity to be used when developing Adobe Flash applications. I'm not that familiar with Flash or ActionScript. I don't even even know if there are some kind of DLL equivalent in Flash/ActionScript.

Any suggestions? Do I have to go the long way, i.e. learn flash and develop this functionallity or, is there a smoother way? A .Net to ActionScript converter?

Comment: No, there is no such thing. ;)

Comment: According to this SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888092/calling-net-dll-function-from-actionscript) you may be able to call your .Net dll from action script.

Answer (score 1):

No.

But you could consider exposing such assembly (DLL) functionalities through a Web Service API, and let both Silverlight and Flash apps access them remotely so both can share the same implementation of your backend.

That will work if the whole assembly it's not doing real-time processing or something like that and the whole Silverlight and Flash apps are browser-based ones. In that case, you can develop an ASP.NET Web API (REST) and do the work in the service.

Later you'll be asynchronously querying the Web API from Flash and Silverlight.

Comment: That may not always be an option.  For example if he wrote a physics engine for a game in .NET, it wouldn't make sense to share functionality by exposing it through web services.

Comment: @R0MANARMY This kind of arguments are edge cases: the OP didn't say it's a game, thus this answer can work. I'm going to update the answer so it can reflect this is as a possible solution if it's not a gaming thing........

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer It's not just about gaming thing, it's about every thing in the world that is not designed to be asynchronous with a client-server communication delay... Every math lib, image lib, encoding lib, misc tools lib...etc. is not designed for a client/server architecture.

Comment: @ken2k Whatever. You don't know what's behind OP's question. My answer is a possible solution for a generic case. If my solution doesn't fit the OP's case, the OP himself/herself will tell me that and I'll adapt my answer to his/her specific needs :D

Comment: Don't get defensive, we're not trying to tear down your answer, just providing an alternate point of view.  We're all here to help each other and learn from each other.

Comment: @R0MANARMY Ok, ok I'm agree ;) I was just saying that sometimes I feel that some comments try to show edge cases and it's like "if if if if if". There're a lot of variables in a solution and, "if" the OP isn't that concrete, who knows. Either my answer or your point of view are valid, because no one knows the underlying problem.

Comment: Even libraries that does processing should be designed async so the UI thread isn't held up, so that argument that processing libraries can't always be async is not right. But yes there are many cases where it doesn't make sense to convert to a web service. I still think its an suggestion that might cover the use case and SL ports easy to ASP.NET if no UI is involved. Alternative is JS instead of Flex/SL which ports to all browsers and you could even call that from SL and Flex